# Find entity by TKey in Repository Pattern<T, TKey>

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, generic-collections

With `Repository Pattern`, I am trying to find an entity by `TKey`. I am trying to find the way to compare `TKey` with `int`

Implementation

```
public interface IRepository<T, TKey>
{
    T GetById(TKey id);
}

public class Repository<T, TKey> : IRepository<T, TKey> where T : class, IEntity<TKey>
{
    private List<T> _context;

    public Repository(List<T> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public T GetById(TKey id)
    {
        return _context.Single(m => m.Id == (TKey)id);
    }
}
```

Here, passing `int` for `TKey`

```
public interface IEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestEntity : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string EntityName { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, Test Client

```
var list = new List<TestEntity>();

list.Add(new TestEntity{ Id = 1 , EntityName = "aaa" });
list.Add(new TestEntity{ Id = 2 , EntityName = "bbb" });

var repo = new Repository<TestEntity, int>(list);
var item = repo.GetById(1);

Console.WriteLine(item);
```

I may not be in the right direction with casting the below way but tried and ran with an error.

```
public T GetById(TKey id)
{
    return _context.Single(m => (object)m.Id == Convert.ChangeType(id, typeof(TKey));
}
```

> [System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element]

How to implement with the same approach without changing the parameter from `TKey id` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate`

Comment: I think you'd be better off using something like `Single(m => m.Id.ToString() == id.ToString());`

Comment: Great!! Simple Solution and I missed it.

Comment: Thanks and Please post this as an answer and along if you think any other best way or any similar better approach for Repo. Pattern. Please post as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all that casting, and definitely no string conversion, because first and foremost `TKey` == `TKey`, and second, not all underlying stores may be able to apply those conversions.

You need to research the actual compiler error that your initial code gave:

> CS0019: Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `TKey` and `TKey`

In order to let C# know it can compare two `TKey`s, you need to constrain `TKey` to `IEquatable<TKey>` and call `.Equals()`:

```
public class Repository<T, TKey> : IRepository<T, TKey>
    where T : class, IEntity<TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    private List<T> _context;

    public Repository(List<T> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public T GetById(TKey id)
    {
        return _context.Single(m => m.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}
```